# Get the Youtube Video Thumbnail from Youtube video Url using PHP

Tags: php, youtube

Lets say I have a youtube video url `www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU&feature=youtube_gdata&par1=1&par2=2`

I want to get the video thumbnail -> i3.ytimg.com/vi/B4CRkpBGQzU/default.jpg
I just need a simple php script that I will input the $url and get the $img
If posible I would like to strip all other parameters and be left with just the
www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU as the $url

Answer (score 20):

To extract the identifier from the following URL :

```
$url = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU&feature=youtube_gdata&par1=1&par2=2';
```

You can first use [**`parse_url()`**](http://www.php.net/parse_url) to get the query string :

```
$queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
var_dump($queryString);
```

Which, here, would give you :

```
string 'v=B4CRkpBGQzU&feature=youtube_gdata&par1=1&par2=2' (length=49)
```

And, then, use [**`parse_str()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to extract the parameters from that query string :

```
parse_str($queryString, $params);
var_dump($params);
```

Which would get you the following array :

```
array
  'v' => string 'B4CRkpBGQzU' (length=11)
  'feature' => string 'youtube_gdata' (length=13)
  'par1' => string '1' (length=1)
  'par2' => string '2' (length=1)
```

And, now, it's just a matter of using the `v` item from that array, injecting it into the thumbnail URL :

```
if (isset($params['v'])) {
    echo "i3.ytimg.com/vi/{$params['v']}/default.jpg";
}
```

Which gives :

```
i3.ytimg.com/vi/B4CRkpBGQzU/default.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, for this perfect solution. just one question, the image that i am getting is too small. how to get bigger image of size 300*300 like that. I have to embed this in email under "Video of the week".

Comment: @Purushottamzende http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
        function getYoutubeImage($e){
        //GET THE URL
        $url = $e;

        $queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

        parse_str($queryString, $params);

        $v = $params['v'];  
        //DISPLAY THE IMAGE
        if(strlen($v)>0){
            echo "<img src='http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/$v/default.jpg' width='150' />";
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    getYoutubeImage("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXWSlho1mMY&feature=plcp");
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: https://img.youtube.com/vi/B4CRkpBGQzU/default.jpg]
[image: https://img.youtube.com/vi/B4CRkpBGQzU/1.jpg]
[image: https://img.youtube.com/vi/B4CRkpBGQzU/2.jpg]
[image: https://img.youtube.com/vi/B4CRkpBGQzU/3.jpg]

```
$url = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=B4CRkpBGQzU";
$url = explode("&", $url);
$vidID = preg_match("|?v=(.*)|", $url);
$thumb_default = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/default.jpg");

$thumb1 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/0.jpg");
$thumb2 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/1.jpg");
$thumb3 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/2.jpg");
$thumb4 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/3.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming youtube doesn't change their format:

`$thumb = preg_match('/watch\?v=(.*)&feature/',$url, $matches);`

This will get you the 'B4CRkpBGQzU' part in `$matches[1];`

Comment: Edited it. Forgot to include $matches. Then just use $matches how you wish to create the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the video ID from the URL

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&amp;feature=relate";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ) );
echo $vidID;//this is video id
```

Getting the images

```
$thumb1 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/0.jpg");
$thumb2 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/1.jpg");
$thumb3 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/2.jpg");
$thumb4 = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$vidID/3.jpg");
```