# How to make gif image from youtube video?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api, gif

Anybody help me i want to developing a website using php code. [GIF-KING](http://www.gif-king.com) this is my website i have completed jpeg image to gif creator but how to create GIF image from YouTube URL like [yt2gif](http://yt2gif.com/)

I tried to search Google but there is not gives any sufficient result to fulfill my requirement.

I got the code upload video to GIF creator but unable to find the script making YouTube URL to GIF creator.

I got one solution first download YouTube video by using YouTube API. then convert it to in GIF images. But that is not the right way. i am unable to convert it in the middle part. Always convert from starting Also it is not possible to download huge number of video from YouTube.

See my process of creating GIF images from YouTube URL.

**Screenshot-1 :**

Copy the YouTube URL
[image]

**Screenshot-2 :**

Paste it in the website http://www.gif-king.com/make-your-gif3 see below screenshot.
[image]

Click on `Create Gifs` after some times the video details will appear See screenshot-3.

**Screenshot-3 :**

[image: Showing the video details from YouTube]

After click on `Make Gif` this video will convert to GIF.

It is working for a small video. but not working it for big video.

My php code:

**ajax.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['vid'])){
    $vidID=$_REQUEST['vid'];
    if($vidID){
        include('curl.php');
        include('youtube.php');
        $tube = new youtube();

        $links = $tube->get("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$vidID);
        $getVideo=$links[3]['url']; //Get the avi video from youtube 
        $cate=mysql_query("select * from category ORDER BY id ");
        while($categoryName=mysql_fetch_array($cate)){
            $getCatRes .= '<option value="'.$categoryName['id'].'">'.$categoryName['name'].'</option>';
        }
        if($getVideo) {
            $url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $vidID;
            $doc = new DOMDocument;
            $doc->load($url);
            $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $duration = $doc->getElementsByTagName('duration')->item(0)->getAttribute('seconds');
            if($duration > 1200){
                $array[] = array('result'=>'error','message'=>'ERROR!!! Maximum 20 minutes video allowed');
            }
            else{
            $newVideo = "gifking_".time().".avi";
            $videoUploaded=file_put_contents("myvideo/".$newVideo,file_get_contents($getVideo));
            if($videoUploaded){
                    $video='<iframe width="360" height="240" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$vidID.'?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3&amp;cc_load_policy=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light"></iframe>';

                    $video_title='<input type="text" class="add-gif-textbox" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="'.$title.'"  />';
                    $category='<select class="add-gif-dropdown" id="cat_id" name="cat_id">
                                  '.$getCatRes.'
                                  </select>';
                    $tag='<input type="text" class="add-gif-textbox" name="tag" id="tag" placeholder="tiger,book,flower" />';
                    $submitBtn='<input id="button" class="button1" type="submit" value="Make Gif" name="submit">';

                    $array[] = array('result'=>'success','title'=>$video_title,'category'=>$category,'video'=>$video,'duration'=>$duration,'tag'=>$tag,'filename'=>$newVideo,'submit_btn'=>$submitBtn);
                }
                else{
                    $array[] = array('result'=>'error','message'=>'ERROR!!! Uploading image please try again');
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $array[] = array('result'=>'error','message'=>'ERROR!!! Invalid video id');
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

Please suggest me how to creating that in php code?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api/2068371#2068371

Comment: this url coming from youtube image. Byt my requirement is i want to convert video to gif image.

Comment: From your question, I cannot see any level of expertise. This is why I'd suggest you hire a programmer.

Comment: @michi i am a programmer. We are 3 developer trying to do this.

Comment: Why did you not just used Google ? There are masses of tutorials...

Comment: I have some minus vote. So i am unable to post question. Please make up vote in my questions.

Comment: @SunilMishra this is not duplicate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works totally easy, lucky for you! Here is a simple step-by-step program of that:

1. You first of all download the video from Youtube (or any other video website not to make it too specific). This can be done with a download program. Those exist, there are popular ones.
2. Then you need a video converter program. Those exist, there are popular ones. With it  you extract each X frames as an image. Take care to get the timing right so you understand the duration in milliseconds between each of those X frames.
3. Then you merge all the image files of the extracted frames again with a software that can create an animated gif. Those exist, there are popular ones. Take care here now that you set the timing right between the frames.
4. Then you save the gif image to a specific filename.

Good News: You are done.

As far as the program of this is concerned (the *programming question*), you find the steps outlined in the list above.

The implementation depends on tool suggestions which are off-topic here on site (but this shouldn't be show stopper for you as each step above is explained in detail within the interwebs and you seem to be clever enough to use the interwebs otherwise you wouldn't have asked on Stackoverflow).

Good luck and have fun. Let us know how it worked out!

Comment: How to extract youtube video to X frames? any php code is there please give me

Comment: Not to X frames but each X (Nth) frames. As already outlined in the answer you do that not a Youtube video specifically but you first download the Youtube video (or any other video) and then do that with a frame extracting program on the video-file. There is no particular difference between an ordinary video file and the one you downloaded from the internet from that provide you can't stop using it's name from but that one is technically uninteresting for the overall process. Just follow the steps in my answer and you should be fine.

Comment: I dont need to download the video from youtube. Just put the url like http://yt2gif.com and make gif images form the youtube url.

Comment: Well technically you're using that website program to download the yourtube video and convert it into a gif. So even then you download the video albeit not you personally and not any of your tools but a walled tool on some remote service. But behind the scene this is what happens. So if you want to do it your own, use that software or another one. As I wrote in my answer: Such programs do exist already.

Comment: Well, this requires contracting first then we can discuss your requirements in detail. Just telling in case you're interested what is necessary for me.

Comment: You misunderstand SO.. You don't get free code here if you haven't even tried, you must hire people for that.

Comment: Hi @hakre i prefer your answer and do step by step which you have mentioned in your answer. It works fine but if i want to convert gif image from a big video. It is not possible to download to covert gif image. have you any other solution please say me?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using something like ffmpeg(multi platform open source library for converting/recording video) to do most of the more difficult work for you. Take a quick look at this
http://www.ffmpeg.org/ and also http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs one of the codes on the second website has one specifically for converting to gif.

You also need to implement the library in PHP, a quick google search reveals many sites that can help you with this. It may involve a plugin or program on the server to allow PHP to automate this process.

I havent done a huge amount of work in PHP but it seems quite possible to convert a youtube video to gif with a bit of work - so i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Brentis56 but i am unable to install ffmpeg in my local system. please tell me how to install ffmpeg in my xampp

Comment: I havent had personal experience with xampp and ffmpeg, but this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977448/install-ffmpeg-on-xampp and also just a general google search for "xampp ffmpeg" brought up multiple results for tutorials. Let me know if you have any more trouble and i can see what I can do!

Comment: Unable to create gif image from youtube. please give me a small example with code @Brentis56

Comment: You need vagrant on xampp for that. then you all run this on some linux that has all those tools. but as I outline in my answer ffmpeg is only one part of the toolchain.

Comment: As hakre has said it requires more then just xampp, you will have to download the video, convert it possibly using xampp, and then save it. It would be too difficult to provide a small example with code as it requires a few tools to complete and isnt an easy task. If you just search the web for each step specifically and then slowly learn from there that would be best. Also it will then be much easier if you run in to any problems for me to provide an example with code as I could be more specific for you making it easier for both of us.

Comment: Hi @brentphillips i follow the line which hakre has said. This code is working but problem is - it is not possible to download big video. I tried search but not getting this type of similar result.

Answer (score 1):

**Soluton: 1**

I got one solution first download YouTube video by using `youtube-to-gif`(if this is not installed your server. Please contact with server support team) shell than convert it to in gif images.

Here is my code:

```
$vodeo_id = 'UiPRwDUGQLE';
$start_second = 5;
$duration = 10;
$filePath = 'some_path_here';
$fileName = 'some_file_name.gif';
exec("youtube-to-gif -u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$video_id} -b $start_second -d $duration -s 550x? -o {$filePath}{$fileName} -f 10", $out, $err);
```

Above is working fine but one problem there. You can't convert to gif from 0 sec. Because `youtube-to-gif` takes default time from 3 sec to onwards.

**Solution: 2**

Here is second thought.
If you want to convert YouTube to GIF image.
You should install following extentions

- FFMEPG ([doc](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html))
- youtube-dl ([doc](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl))

If above extensions not installed in your server please contact your server support team.

First download YouTube video by using `youtube-dl` command. Then you easily use `ffmpeg` command for convert to GIF image.

Here is my code:

```
$input = 'your video path which you was downloading from YouTube by using youtube-dl commmand';
$start = 5;
$end = 15;
$limit = $end - $start;
$thumbnail = 'img/logo.png'; /* adding watermark on that GIF image */

$storeFolder = 'destination path here';
$targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . $ds . $storeFolder;
$newName = time() . '.gif';
$destinationPath = $targetPath . $newName;

$command = "ffmpeg -t $limit -ss $start -i $input -i $thumbnail -vf scale=500:-1 -codec:a copy $destinationPath";
@exec($command, $ret, $returnvalue);
if ($returnvalue == 127) {
      $data['message'] = "FFMPEG not installed. Please contact with support team.";
} else {
     $data['message'] = "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would be more specific and expand on my answer as its quite difficult with the character limit in the comments:

As mentioned you will have to follow a few steps. First you must get the video from youtube to convert it:
In php you could try a file_get_contents() on the page that refrences the video(or some other download method a simple search for "php download youtube video" reveals many.

Then you will have to convert it to gif. xampp and ffmpeg would be suited to the task though another search of the web with just "convert to gif php" revealed a few options. A found a few tutorials also through that search so it shouldnt be too hard. You should also check out the xampp and ffmpeg websites and see the documentation on them if you choose to go with that.

Once converted you must save the gif with a specific filename, that shouldnt be too hard it also depends on what method youve used to convert it, once again there is plenty of documentation out there to help with this sort of stuff.

So see how it goes and although it would take way too long and be too difficult to show you an example on stackoverflow, if you have a slightly more specific question about one of the steps id be happy to find you a tutorial or try and get a small example working for you. Try your best and im sure with a bit of searching around and effort you'll be able to find out how to do it in no time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure PHP solution, but I would advise you to use an external application (via command-line) to make this conversion, simple because PHP is not fast enough to do this kind of video manipulations frequently. The loading times and server load would be awfull.

For the pure PHP solution you could use this class to convert the video file to frames (as, let's say gif images):
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html

And then the next solution to convert the images to frames of a .gif image:
[PHP - Create simple animated GIF from two JPEG images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191367/php-create-simple-animated-gif-from-two-jpeg-images)

For the terminal-based solution, you could take a look at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast

You could also make a connection to a custom application based in another language (let's say; python or C++) and let this program do the hard convertion, while PHP does the rest (maybe creating the GUI?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate gif/image file when you upload file, refer to ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -i orginal.avi -t 10 output.gif
```

-i: the video file name
 -t: is the time

if you want to call existed image file with youtube video, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808013/get-the-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-youtube-video-url-using-php)

Comment: I got the make gif from upload video script. But i want to know how to make from youtube url?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is something out of the box for your task.

You should develop something to do this.

For example you can:

1. Download youtube video with this node.js plugin: https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl
2. Convert it with gif.js: http://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/tests/video.html

Comment: Hi i am trying but not doing that. Give me a little source code

Answer (score 0):

Google supply a Youtube API for tasks relating to Youtube videos, image urls included.
[Youtube-Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use external API [YouTube video to gif Animation](https://www.mashape.com/squbit/youtube-video-to-gif-animation#!endpoint-Create-Animation).

Sample PHP Code:

```
$response = Unirest::post(
  "https://squbit-video-to-animation.p.mashape.com/animation",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Authorization" => "Mashape-Authorization-Key",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
  ),
  "{\"sourceId\":\"ZL6a4U_UdTc\",\"width\":\"480\",\"height\":\"270\",\"startTime\":\"192\",\"duration\":\"17\",\"callback\":\"http:\/\/yourhost.com\/callback\/\"}"
);
```

You specify input parameters in JSON request.

Once your animation is ready you will receive a callback to http://yourhost.com/callback_url/ with a link to created gif animation

Thank you